# How to access local kubernete cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed 1 master and 3 nodes on VM's.
I can run successfully "kubectl" command on the server's SSH CLI. I can deploy pods, all fine.

But I couldn't find how can I run "kubectl" command from my local and manage the K8S cluster? How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the error you're getting. By deploying pods, do you mean running "kubectl create"? If so, you should be good to get pods too.

Comment: This is not an "error" issue, I can't access my local K8S cluster deployed on our DC. I want to access from my local laptop. Means I want to run kubectl command from my laptop.

Comment: Yes, so when you run "kubectl get ns" what do you get? Because if you can deploy pods, assuming from your local machine, it means you're connected.

Comment: When I run "kubectl get ns" command, it shows my Azure's k8S's namespaces. But I want to connect my local cluster which deployed on our DC.

Comment: Run "kubectl config get-contexts", which will list all the clusters you've in your config file. Then run "kubectl config use-context cluster-name" , this will point kubectl to communicate with that cluster. Replace 'cluster-name' with whatever the name is for your local cluster. If it's not listed, it means you haven't got to context file to it.

Comment: thanks! Do you know where these informations storing at Windows? I mean for example output of "kubectl config view"? From a local file or?

Comment: No problem. Run > %USERPROFILE%/.kube/config - this will output your config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your local machine run:

> kubectl config get-contexts

Then run the below (replace cluster-name with the cluster name you want to communicate with):

> kubectl config use-context cluster-name

If the cluster name you want to communicate with is not listed, it means you haven't got to context file to the cluster.

Answer (score 3):

You might have a kubeconfig file somewhere on the VMs. You can copy this one to your local device under `$HOME/.kube/config`, so kubectl knows how to access the cluster.

For more information, see the [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/).